# White spaces between divs

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm getting white spaces (horizontal) between divs on the bottom and top and I don't know the reason.

```css
#header {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#header #date {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#header #date #date_day_month {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 75px;
  background-color: #E96567;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#header #date #date_day {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #DB5658;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#header #logo {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DB5658;
  min-height: 30px;
}
#header #logo_comment {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 110%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="date">
      <div id="date_day_month">
        hoi
      </div>
      <div id="date_day">
        hoi
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <div id="logo_comment">
        Hoi
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

I notice that as I run this code here in stack, this problem is not active.. However in the fiddle it is clearly for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/njk96/28/

----------------------- EDIT:

Using chrome, the newest version, on my dell xps 13 (9434) and not zoomed in or out.
http://postimg.org/image/ggbkubiyz/ (my screenshot)

Comment: I'm not seeing it in the fiddle

Comment: Same here; the fiddle looks much like the snippet. Do you have the page zoomed in or out, by any chance?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ggbkubiyz/ home i'm not the one who's getting crazy here :D

Comment: comment out your space in the code.. meaning: '</endtag><!---comment--><starttag>' and see if this clears your problems, if so i have a solution for you

Comment: It's because of `background-color:#FFF;` in `#header #logo_comment`.  Try changing that

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs http://jsfiddle.net/njk96/29/ didn't work...

Comment: @Pugazh http://jsfiddle.net/njk96/30/ that is not the reason have you seen my image?

Comment: Can you edit the question with details on what platform you're using? The screenshot looks like it's from a retina screen, right? Or are you zoomed in after all?

Comment: Are you using Dreamweaver?

Comment: That's a hi-dpi screen; apparently that works a bit different than 96dpi monitors. I tried to emutate that with Chrome, but to no avail.

Comment: @MrLister i'm sorry but i won't agree with your answer. This problem is something i've never seen before and i'm simulating the code with two other divs, and i have not got this problem there. Ergo there must be something in this code that's the bug...

Comment: I'm asking because Dreamweaver sometimes ads extra space. Try padding; 0 and see what happens. Test it.

Comment: @super11 Thx for your input, have never had that behavior of dreamweaver  (i don't use there live view though). But i did what you said and there's no difference. Thanks though

Comment: @MartHaarman I was trying to say I can't duplicate the problem here. According to my 96dpi monitor, there is no problem with your code. I wasn't trying to provide an answer, since I have none.

Comment: @MrLister never heard some coder say this, but there must be something with my code ;(

Comment: Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: @super11 sorry not working. I have found out that as i remove the line-height and height part of the #header #date #date_day_month part it works like it should.. however that is not an option today ;)

Comment: It works on my screen, I can post a screenshot if you wish.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another option.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    display: initial;
}
```

or use:

```
body {
    display: inline;
}
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an
>   element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element
>   for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property.

Comment: Not the working solutions.. What worked now is editing my line-height from 75px to 74 px and it all works out now. Still odd